# Can not create Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

It seams some key has expired and thus I have to create a new Provisioning Profile. Now that should not be to hard, so I do it and while doing it the assistant tells me

```
No Certificates are available.

Click "Create Certificate." to create a Certificate. You need a Certificate to configure a Provisioning Profile.
```

All right, no problem. I do it and it works.

I have a new Certificate with 'Type: APNs Production iOS' 'Expires: Mar 03, 2015' that sounds good. I download it and add it to Keychain Access.

I go back to Provisioning Profiles but again I get

```
No Certificates are available.

Click "Create Certificate." to create a Certificate. You need a Certificate to configure a Provisioning Profile.
```

What the hell is going on? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Type: APNs Production iOS' 'Expires: Mar 03, 2015"
That's not the certificate you're looking for, it's a certificate to use on your server to be able to use Apple's push notifications.

You must create an "iOS App Development" or "App Store and Ad Hoc" certificate.

Comment: That is great after I searched for a answer for over a day I figure it out myself and then exactly 5 min later I get your answer. Thanks anyway.